# pst-text with plain XeTeX

Tags: xetex, pstricks, plain-tex

How, if possible, can I use `pst-text` with plain XeTeX? I have TeX Live 2011.

When I try to run the minimal example:

```
\input pst-text

\pscharpath{TeXnik}
\bye
```

, I get a bunch of `** WARNING`'s, among them:

```
** WARNING ** Failed to read converted PSTricks image file.
```

and

```
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PST: (ps:) failed.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not supposed to work (this way), or is there some step I'm missing?

I don't get any warnings or anything weird in the logfile, but I do to the terminal:

```
Ilmalaiva% xetex pikakoe.tex 
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pikakoe.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-text/pst-text.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
we are running tex and have to define some LaTeX commands ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvtxhdr.tex
2005/02/22 v1.1 xkeyval TeX header (HA))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.20  <2011/04/23> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/xetex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.
cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/xetex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.
cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))  v1.00, 2006/11/05(tvz,hv)) [1]
** WARNING ** pdf_open: Not a PDF 1.[1-5] file.
** WARNING ** Failed to include image file "/var/folders/2w/40kkgr916n34r23ts240d9bh0000gn/T//dvipdfmx.8Yyf2pkO"
** WARNING ** >> Please check if
** WARNING ** >>   rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit
** WARNING ** >>   %o = output filename, %i = input filename, %b = input filename without suffix
** WARNING ** >> can really convert "/var/folders/2w/40kkgr916n34r23ts240d9bh0000gn/T//dvipdfmx.8Yyf2pkO" to PDF format image.
** WARNING ** pdf: image inclusion failed for "/var/folders/2w/40kkgr916n34r23ts240d9bh0000gn/T//dvipdfmx.8Yyf2pkO".
** WARNING ** Failed to read converted PSTricks image file.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command PST: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(123.75, 759.927)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "PST: tx@Dict begin gsave STV /ArrowA { moveto } def /ArrowB { }"
 )
Output written on pikakoe.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on pikakoe.log.
```

Comment: I do not get any warning with current TeXLive

Comment: @Marco: Why did you remove the {plain-tex} tag?

Comment: @Caradimir: I think `plain-tex` is something which is compiled with `tex`. `xetex`/`xelatex` is a special deployment of `tex` That's the reason. 
I also tested the example and I had also no errors.

Comment: @Herbert: I forgot to add the word "basic" to the TL-version I'm using (TeX Live 2011 basic). Also I'm on OSX 10.7. I'm guessing I'm missing something really basic; looking at one of the lines which starts off with "Please check if rungs...", makes me wonder if that `rungs`'s `gs` comes from `GhostScript`?

Comment: @Marco: plain-tex is a format. XeTeX is an engine.

Comment: @morbusg: Ok -- We need an explanation in the wiki

Comment: it looks like that your `xdvipdfmx` conversion failed. Do you have it installed?

Comment: @Herbert: yes: `% which xdvipdfmx  /usr/texbin/xdvipdfmx`

Comment: @Marco: which wiki are you referring to? By the way, thanks for the (other) edits; they clarified the output nicely! `:-)`

Comment: @morbusg: then run it by hand: `xetex -no-pdf <file>` and then `xdvipdfmx <file>.xdv`. What happens?

Comment: @morbusg: I mean this tag: http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/plain-tex/info

Comment: @Herbert: I get the same `** WARNING **`-lines as in the question's terminal output.

Comment: with `xetex` or with `xdvipdfmx`?

Comment: @Herbert: with `xdvipdfmx`.

Comment: I have this version: `This is xdvipdfmx-0.7.8 by Jonathan Kew and Jin-Hwan Cho, ...`

Comment: @Herbert: I have the same version. I'm wondering if I am missing some crucial program. Is there a list of requirements somewhere?

Comment: then run the ghostscript by hand as described in the error message. Instead of `rungs` it maybe `gs`

Comment: @Herbert: old question, but in hoping to bring a closure to it; I take it I have to have GhostScript installed? i.e., it doesn't take advantage of OSX's native postscript tools? If that's the case, then the obvious answer is: "You need to have GhostScript installed" `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) installed.

Answer (score 1):

here is my log:

```
voss@shania:~> xetex Namenlos-2.tex 
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Namenlos-2.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/generic/pst-text/pst-text.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/generic/pstricks/generic/pstricks.t
ex
we are running tex and have to define some LaTeX commands ...
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvtxhdr.tex
2005/02/22 v1.1 xkeyval TeX header (HA))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/generic/pstricks/generic/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.22  <2011/07/09> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/xetex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.c
fg)) (/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/xetex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.c
fg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))  v1.00, 2006/11/05(tvz,hv)) [1] )
Output written on Namenlos-2.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on Namenlos-2.log.
```

the files in my local tree are the same as on TeXLive 2011

Comment: This post doesn't even nearly count as an answer. It doesn't contain any algorithm to solve the problem.

Comment: that is obvious, that is was _not_ an answer.

Comment: It is a blog on a log.